# d3.js, multiple script tags blocking eachother

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, rendering

I am new to JavaScript and HTML, and am writing my first webpage. I want to insert two different visualisations made with d3.js (which each have different .js files) in my html file. The second is not rendering and seems to be blocked by the first. Here is the html where I source them:

```
<body>
.....
<script src="js/d3_basic_bar.js"></script>
<script src="js/d3_basic_scatter.js"></script>
</body>
```

The first visualisation associated with d3_basic_bar.js is rendering, but the second isn't, how can I get both to render on the page?

Thanks

Comment: The information provided by you is not enough to resolve this issue. Please provide the entire code either in codesandbox or here only. Please attach screenshots of console errors if you are getting any

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since been resolved, common variables blocked each script from running concurrently.